# Apply a function on sub-tensors in a way that can be parallelized (Pytorch)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch

Lets say I have a Pytorch function `f` that can be applied to a tensor of shape `shape_in=(d1,...,dn)` and returns a tensor of shape `shape_out`. Now I have a tensor `T` of shape `(other_shape,shape_in)=(b1,...,bm,d1,...,dn)`. How can I apply `f` to `T` to return a tensor of shape `(other_shape,shape_out)` in a way that can be parallelized? I dont think just looping over all elements of a tensor of shape `other_shape` would be optimal since the computations would probably be done sequentially (is this right?). I think `map_fn` in Tensorflow does exactly that but I havnt seen an equivalent in torch.

Comment: I don't think PyTorch has anything like TensorFlow's `map_fn`, which does not seem to be that efficient according to [Issue #24774 - why is tensorflow.map_fn slow, what is wrong with following code?](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24774). Any vectorised version is the better choice, but there is no generic version, so it depends what your function `f` does. From the example you gave, that looks like a matrix multiplication ([`torch.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.matmul)) as multiplying an *m x n* with an *n x p*  matrix results in an *m x p* matrix.

Comment: Is there a reason there isnt anything like a generalized method for application of a function to subtensors (besides vectorisation which is often tricky or impossible)? something like numpy.apply_along_axis. And why map_fn works so slow?